# How to remove scientific notation in nodejs/html and display in decimal only?

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, handlebars.js, amazon-ses

I am using a node JS app to send an email using amazon SES using the `ses.sendTemplatedEmail` API

I have also mentioned the template's pure html file for reference if need be

how do i achieve expected output ? i don't know what is going wrong and why it is using scientific when decimal is specified in JSON

**test.js**

```
const aws=require('aws-sdk')
const ses = new aws.SES({ apiVersion: "2020-12-01",region:"us-east-1"});
var a = {
    "Items": [
        {
            "timeSinceInactive": 0.00011574074074074075,
            "id": "myid1",
            "ssid": "myssid",
            "deviceName": "devicename1"
        },
        {
            "timeSinceInactive": 0.00009259259259259259,
            "id": "myid2",
            "ssid": "myssid2",
            "deviceName": "devicename2"
        }
    ]
}
b = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(b)
async function sesSendEmail(b,ses) {
    var params = {
      Source: "abc@gmail.com",
      Template: "mytemplatename",
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["xyz@gmail.com"] // Email address/addresses that you want to send your email
      },
      TemplateData: b,
    }
    try {
      await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise()
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      throw new Error(err)
    }
  };
  function setAwsCredentials() {
    awsCredentials = {
      region: "us-east-1",
      accessKeyId: "",
      secretAccessKey: ""
    };
    aws.config.update(awsCredentials);
    console.log("Set credentials successfully")
  }
setAwsCredentials()
sesSendEmail(b,ses)
```

**template.html**

```
<table border='2' width='1000'>
    <tr>
        <th>timeSinceInactive</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>ssid</th>
        <th>deviceName</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each Items.[0]}}
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each Items}}
        <tr>
            {{#each this}}
            <td>
                 {{this}}
            </td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Current output**:

```
timeSinceInactive        id      ssid    deviceName
1.1574074074074075E-4   myid1   myssid  devicename1
9.259259259259259E-5    myid2   myssid2 devicename2
```

**desired output**

```
timeSinceInactive        id      ssid    deviceName
0.00011574074074074075  myid1   myssid  devicename1
0.00009259259259259259  myid2   myssid2 devicename2
```

**EDIT**

I need to sort the data as well so converting it to a string is not a feasible alternative unfortunately.

**Note**

I am using createTemlate API from Amazon SES which supports handlebars.. so the html code is using handlebars by default... that is causing the issue its making it in scientific notation for some reason how do i make it decimal only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider converting the numbers to strings before passing them to the template. That way you have control over the formatting.

Comment: Nope cannot do that i need to sort the data aswell i will add that to my question.. anyways appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

To my mind you should switch to a template that is less generic and make a call to a custom helper that would display the number as you want. The template will look like this one :

```
<table border='2' width='1000'>
    <tr>
        <th>timeSinceInactive</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>ssid</th>
        <th>deviceName</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each Items.[0]}}
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each Items}}
        <tr>
            <td>
               {{customFormatNumber timeSinceInactive}}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{id}}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{ssid}}
            </td>
            <td>
               {{deviceName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the custom helper that you could write (this is just an example, probably not the one you want exactly) :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('customFormatNumber ', function(item, options) {
    retrun item.toPrecision(10)
});
```

Comment: I am not requiring handlebars template in my NodeJS app .. handlebars is supported by amazon SES by default.. so when i register a html snippet using handlebars Amazon SES is able to read it... So now the question is how do i do something like `Handlebars.registerHelper`  to tell handlebars which is supported by Amazon SES that such a function exists ? i dont think it is possible... thoughts on this ??

Comment: Yes you're right it's not possible. Sorry I didn't knew that it was so limited. I see only the string solution given by @JasonWadsworth then. Without any customization handlebars is too limited

Comment: please don't be sorry i really appreciate you trying to help :) .. and yeah i'll try to go with that after sorting should work then